# Check if value input in textbox exists in database and insert if not

Tags: c#, mysql

How to check if the text I input in textbox already exists in database and if so update only the data or anything solution you recommend and if not the data will automatically insert into database? Here is my code:

```
 cn.Open();
        cm = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblcustomer WHERE fullname LIKE '" + txtCustomer.Text + "'", cn);
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {

            
            cm = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE tblcustomer SET fullname = '" + txtCustomer.Text + "' WHERE id LIKE '" + lblCustomerId.Text + "'", cn);
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
           

        }
        else
        {
            
            cm = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblcustomer(fullname) VALUES ('" + txtCustomer.Text + "')", cn);
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
           
        }

        dr.Close();
        cn.Close();
```

Comment: This isn't a question about using the Visual Studio application, so I've removed the tag. Please ensure you read tag descriptions so as not to misuse them.

Comment: usually you would try to get the value from data base and update it. if you don't get anything then you insert a new one

Comment: @MongZhu that's right. I'm trying to get value form database so I need to update the database if the data is existing.

Comment: but then I don't understand what you problem is. Please use parametrized queries and avoid sql injection

Answer (score 0):

Change your SQL to this:
"INSERT INTO tblcustomer fullname VALUES" + txtCustomer.Text + "
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fullname= " + txtCustomer.Text

Pseudo, didn't validate this, but it is sort of the right idea, of what you want. And does it in a single connection attempt to the DB.

You can find a guide here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: in else statement? or should I remove else statement and add it on if statement?

Comment: No no. 

The query does the lookup for you, if you have duplicate primary key, it does an update, if the primary key doesn't exist, it does an insert. 

The SQL query, is a single execution, no need to ask, if something exists, the query looks it up for you.

The only problem is, if you don't have the primary key, then you have to do the look up first. But then you simply ask for the object back, and if it has a PK, you set it on the object.